# C++ - are these threads destroyed after the for loop is completed

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    thread *t = new thread(example_function);
    t->join();
}
```

I am doing something similar in a coding project of mine and was wondering if since the threads get defined inside the loop they are destroyed after the loop ends (I know the pointer to the thread probably gets deleted but what about the thread itself?).

Comment: Generally when you use new, you allocate memory and you need to use delete to remove it or the memory region will remain allocated until the program ends

Comment: @TemaniAfif You probably meant `delete`.

Comment: @Ron yes ! free is with malloc, just a mistake ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `thread` objects created inside the `for` loop are not destroyed, which means that they create memory leaks.

In order to make sure that the threads are destroyed you need to call `delete` on them in one of several ways:

- Call `delete` at the end of the scope, or
- Add thread pointers to a container of pointers, and call `delete` in a separate loop, or
- Add thread pointer to a smart pointer that ensures deletion when the scope ends, or
- Add thread pointers to a container of smart pointers, and let the container delete the threads when it goes out of scope.

Note that since you are calling `join` on each loop iteration your "concurrent" program is as good as a single-threaded one. Here is how to run your threads concurrently, and ensure thread deletions at the end:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::thread>>> threads;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    threads.push_back(std::make_unique<thread>(example_function));
}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    threads[i]->join();
}
```

Once `threads` vector goes out of scope, it deletes `std::unique_ptr<thread>` objects inside it, which in turn calls `delete` on the individual `std::thread` objects.

Comment: @user3572917 Yea, because you don't immediately wait for the thread you just started. You create them all, then start waiting for each.

Comment: `make_unique` does not need `new` inside  (not to say that whole dynamic allocation is unnecessary)

Comment: @Slava You are right, they forward parameters to the actual `new`. Thank you! Ah, and you are right about there being no need for dynamic allocation in this example.

Answer (score 2):

> I am doing something similar in a coding project of mine and was wondering if since the threads get defined inside the loop they are destroyed after the loop ends

Whole purpose of dynamic allocation using operator `new` is to provide manual control over object lifetime. So no, until you explicitly call `delete` or you use a smart pointer that does it for you under the hood your object would not be destroyed. Note, calling `std::thread::join()` inside the loop effectively would make your program single threaded. More proper use would be:

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
while( threads.size() < 10 )
    threads.emplace_back(example_function);

for( auto &thread : threads )
    thread.join(); // join in a separate loop, let all threads to start

threads.clear(); // or let it go out of scope
```

Comment: I was thinking about the same, except for putting the code into `{ }` to make a scope for concurrent execution.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
thread *t = new thread(example_function);
```

you already loose the formerly allocated `thread` instance and have a memory leak.

`join()` doesn't free the allocated memory, but picks up the asynchonously ended function.

Answer (score 0):

No. The caller is responsible for ensuring objects allocated using `new` are `delete`d.

The code is of course pretty pointless because no meaningful concurrency occurs but to avoid a memory leak should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    thread *t = new thread(example_function);
    t->join();
    delete t;
}
```

In any version of C++11 onwards it is recommended you use `std::unique_ptr` in these cases:

The most recommended form is:

```
auto t{std::make_unique<std::thread>(example_function)};
```

Which is almost equivalent to:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::thread> t(new std::thread(example_function));
```

A `std::unique_ptr` is an object that has operator overloading to behave a lot like a pointer with the difference of deleting the thing it points to (if anything) at the end of its life-time.